# Get MethodInfo from expression without knowing method signature

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I'm trying to pass an expression that describes a method but I want the argument to be strongly typed and I don't want to have to know the method signature or pass the arguments in the expression, something like this:

```
GetMethod<MyClass>(c => c.DoSomething);
```

Where `DoSomething` could have a method signature like this... `string DoSomething(int id, int count)`

I know I can do something like this:

```
MemberInfo GetMethod<T>(Expression<Func<T, Delegate>> expression);

//implementation
GetMethod<MyClass>(c => new Func<int, int, string>(c.DoSomething))
```

But frankly, this is quite ugly.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just have an overload for each possible Action/Func.  It won't cover *all* possibilities (have an extra overload that you've shown there to cover all edge cases) but it'll handle most of them.

The body of each of the action/func overloads can just call the overload that you've shown above for the actual implementation.

```
public MemberInfo GetMethod<T1, T2>(Expression<Func<T1, Func<T2>>> expression)
{
    return GetMethodImpl(expression);
}

public MemberInfo GetMethod<T1, T2, T3>(Expression<Func<T1, Func<T2, T3>>> expression)
{
    return GetMethodImpl(expression);
}

public MemberInfo GetMethod<T1, T2>(Expression<Func<T1, Action<T2>>> expression)
{
    return GetMethodImpl(expression);
}

//...
```

`GetMethodImpl` can then be implemented like so:

```
private MemberInfo GetMethodImpl<T1, T2>(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> expression)
{

}
```

That will be able to be just a slight modification of your existing `GetMethod` implementation.  `T2` will be your delegate; you may need to cast it to `Delegate`, depending on how you use it.

Comment: I'm looking for something more scalable. There could potentially be tens, if not hundreds, of different method signatures.

Comment: @bflemi3 There are only 16? different overloads to Func and Action, each.  That's a finite list.  Generics help handle the permutations that scale it up to a huge level.  As long as you don't have a lot of methods with more than 16 arguments it's not a huge issue.  It won't handle any methods with `ref`/`out` arguments, optional arguments, `params` arguments, or possibly a few other edge cases.  For those you'll need to use the method you showed in the OP as it's probably just not worth dealing with special overloads just for them.

Comment: Would you mind giving me a quick implementation example? I guess using `string DoSomething(int id, int count)`

Comment: @bflemi3 The implementation is whatever you had to begin with.  The idea is that this ensures compile time safety in behalf of the caller, but then turns the strongly typed delegate into just a `Delegate` and does whatever you were doing before.  I have no idea what that is.

Comment: I'm confused then, which signature above would match my implementation?

Comment: @bflemi3 Hmm, I guess upon reflection you won't be able to just call your implementation directly.  Can you create an implementation that accepts an `Expression<Func<T1, T2>>` and use that?

Comment: Wouldn't `Expression<Func<T1, T2, T3>>` work for `string DoSomething(int id, int count)`?

Comment: @bflemi3 No, you have two levels of indirection.  In this case `T2` will be typed to a particularly type of delegate, *that* delegate will match whatever is passed in, thanks to the various overloads that are shown here.

Comment: Ah, is that why you have a `Func` in a `Func`? That was confusing me.

Comment: Sorry, one more question? What would `GetMethodImpl` signature look like?

Comment: I've posted a question directly related to the implementation of your answer. Perhaps you could help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837112/why-cant-i-convert-expression-body-to-methodcallexpression/16837554?noredirect=1#16837554