# Why can't I convert Expression Body to MethodCallExpression

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, expression

Given the following class:

```
public class MyClass {

    private readonly UrlHelper _urlHelper;

    // constructor left out for brevity

    // this is one of many overloaded methods
    public ILinkableAction ForController<TController, T1, T2>(Expression<Func<TController, Func<T1, T2>>> expression) {
        return ForControllerImplementation(expression);
    }

    private ILinkableAction ForControllerImplementation<TController, TDelegate>(Expression<Func<TController, TDelegate>> expression) {
        var linkableMethod = new LinkableAction(_urlHelper);

        var method = ((MethodCallExpression) expression.Body).Method;
        method.GetParameters().ToList().ForEach(p => linkableMethod.parameters.Add(new Parameter {
            name = p.Name,
            parameterInfo = p
        }));

        return linkableMethod;
    }
}
```

and the following implementation:

```
var myClass = new MyClass(urlHelper);
myClass.ForController<EventsController, int, IEnumerable<EventDto>>(c => c.GetEventsById);
```

where `GetEventsById` has the signature:

```
IEnumerable<EventDto> GetEventsById(int id);
```

I'm getting the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression'.

1. How can I convert the expression to the appropriate type to get the `MethodInfo` of the given expression?
2. `TDelegate`, in the above example, is `Func<int, IEnumerable<EventDto>>` at runtime. So being that it's a `Delegate` why am I not able to get the `MethodInfo` from the expression?

Comment: See my answer below. The issue is that your delegate signatures do not match. So the expression body is represented as a Unary (conversion).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that a `MethodCallExpression` has to actually be a method. Consider:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Express(str => str.Length);
    Console.ReadLine();
}


static void Express(Expression<Func<String, Int32>> expression)
{
    // Outputs: PropertyExpression (Which is a form of member expression)
    Console.WriteLine(expression.Body.GetType()); 
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Expressions are determined at compile time, which means when I say `str => str.Length` I'm calling a *property* on `str` and so the compiler resolves this to a `MemberExpression`.

If I instead change my lambda to look like this:

```
Express(str => str.Count());
```

Then the compiler understands that I'm calling `Count()` on `str` and so it resolves to a `MethodCallExpression` ... because it's actually a method.

Note though, that this means you can't really 'convert' expressions from one type to another, any more than you can 'convert' a `String` into an `Int32`. You can do a parse, but I think you get that that's not really a conversation...

...that said, you can BUILD a `MethodCallExpression` from nothing, which is helpful in some cases. For example, let's build the lambda:

```
(str, startsWith) => str.StartsWith(startsWith)
```

(1) First we need to start by building the two parameters: `(str, startsWith) => ...`

```
// The first parameter is type "String", and well call it "str"
// The second parameter also type "String", and well call it "startsWith"
ParameterExpression str = Expression.Parameter(typeof(String), "str");
ParameterExpression startsWith = Expression.Parameter(typeof(String), "startsWith");
```

(2) Then on the right hand side, we need to build: `str.StartsWith(startsWith)`. First we need to use reflection to bind to the `StartsWith(...)` method of `String` that takes a single input of type `String`, like so:

```
// Get the method metadata for "StartsWith" -- the version that takes a single "String" input.
MethodInfo startsWithMethod = typeof(String).GetMethod("StartsWith", new [] { typeof(String) });
```

(3) Now that we have the binding-metadata, we can use a `MethodCallExpression` to actually call the method, like so:

```
//This is the same as (...) => str.StartsWith(startsWith);
// That is: Call the method pointed to by "startsWithMethod" bound above. Make sure to call it
// on 'str', and then use 'startsWith' (defined above as well) as the input.
MethodCallExpression callStartsWith = Expression.Call(str, startsWithMethod, new Expression[] { startsWith });
```

(4) Now we have the left side `(str, startsWith)` / and the right side `str.StartsWith(startsWith)`. Now we just need to join them into one lambda. Final code:

```
// The first parameter is type "String", and well call it "str"
// The second parameter also type "String", and well call it "startsWith"
ParameterExpression str = Expression.Parameter(typeof(String), "str");
ParameterExpression startsWith = Expression.Parameter(typeof(String), "startsWith");

// Get the method metadata for "StartsWith" -- the version that takes a single "String" input.
MethodInfo startsWithMethod = typeof(String).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(String) });

// This is the same as (...) => str.StartsWith(startsWith);
// That is: Call the method pointed to by "startsWithMethod" bound above. Make sure to call it
// on 'str', and then use 'startsWith' (defined above as well) as the input.
MethodCallExpression callStartsWith = Expression.Call(str, startsWithMethod, new Expression[] { startsWith });

// This means, convert the "callStartsWith" lambda-expression (with two Parameters: 'str' and 'startsWith', into an expression
// of type Expression<Func<String, String, Boolean>
Expression<Func<String, String, Boolean>> finalExpression =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<String, String,  Boolean>>(callStartsWith, new ParameterExpression[] { str, startsWith });

// Now let's compile it for extra speed!
Func<String, String, Boolean> compiledExpression = finalExpression.Compile();

// Let's try it out on "The quick brown fox" (str) and "The quick" (startsWith)
Console.WriteLine(compiledExpression("The quick brown fox", "The quick")); // Outputs: "True"
Console.WriteLine(compiledExpression("The quick brown fox", "A quick")); // Outputs: "False"
```

**Update**
Well, maybe something like this might work:

```
class Program
{
        public void DoAction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("actioned");
        }

        public delegate void ActionDoer();

        public void Do()
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Express(Expression<Func<Program, ActionDoer>> expression)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
            Func<Program, ActionDoer> function = expression.Compile();
            function(program).Invoke();
        }

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Express(program => program.DoAction);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

**Update**:
Came across something on accident. Consider this code:

```
    public static String SetPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T, Object>> expression)
    {
        UnaryExpression convertExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)convertExpression.Operand;
        return memberExpression.Member.Name;

        ...
    }
```

The input is a simple lambda for WPF:

```
base.SetPropertyChanged(x => x.Visibility);
```

since I'm projecting into an `Object`, I noticed that visual studio converts this into a `UnaryExpression`, which I think is the same problem you're running into. If you put a break-point and examine the actual expression (in my case) it says `x => Convert(x.Visibility)`. The problem is the `Convert` (which is effectively just a cast to a currently unknown type). All you have to do is remove it (as I do in the code above by using the `Operand` member, and you should be all set. Maybe you'll have your `MethodCallExpression`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, since I'm not calling the method (ie: `getEventById()`) the compiler doesn't know that this is in fact a method and instead treats it as a `UnaryExpression`? How then would I get the `MethodInfo` of the method I've passed in the expression?

Comment: If it is in fact a method, then just use the lambda `m => m.Method()`. Make sure to use the `()`.

Comment: The point of this class and method is to be able to pass a strongly typed pointer to a method. I'm not actually calling the method, just getting the parameters that the method requires. By passing `m => m.Method()` as the expression I would need to also pass the arguments in the lambda but there are no arguments to pass at this point. I suppose I could pass the defaults of the arguments, but it defeats the purpose of declaring the type parameters in the `ForController` method signature. Does that make sense?

Comment: I will say though, this a very good explanation of why I'm getting the error. Thank you for this

Comment: I figured you were getting at something like that, so what you'll have to do is use reflection to bind to the actual method you want, and then construct a `MethodCallExpression`/Compile it yourself. The example shows how to do this. Work the example once, and then it should be fairly straightforward how to do it.

Comment: Still confused. If `ForController` accepts an expression of `Expression<Func<TController, Func<T1, T2>>>` then shouldn't the compiler know that `TDelegate` in `ForControllerImplementation` is at least a `Delegate` and because of that I shouldn't need to construct the `MethodCallExpression` myself, I should be able to cast my way to it right?

Comment: If it is a delegate, make sure to mark the method as `where TDelegate : Delegate`.

Comment: Can't use system.Delegate as type parameter constraint

Comment: Hmm, `Expression<Func<TController, TDelegate>> expression` coupled with `c => c.getEventsById` can never work as is because the compiler will never emit a `MethodCallExpression` from that. Also, since it's an *expression* but not actual *code* you can't really run it as is either. You miiight be able to call `.Compile` on your expression and get working delegate ... but I've never tried that. lemme see....

Comment: Yeah, even if you pass in a delegate, the delegate by itself doesn't know what to point to, so you'd ultimately have to point it to some method... which puts us back at square one. In essence, whatever 'name' is passed in using your lambda will have to manually be bound to the actual `MethodInfo` and then built into a `MethodCallExpression`/Compiled. Basically, this is because *you're not actually passing in a method*, so you need to set up the binding yourself.

Comment: Oh yeah, so one last important thing. Remember that a method can be overloaded. So if you say `x => x.getEventByID()`, the compiler treats that as a *method*, but if you say `x => x.getEventByID`, the compiler treats that as a *method group*, which makes a world of difference (and is the source of your problem here).

Comment: `ForControllerImplementation(Expression<Func<TController, TDelegate>> expression)` is actually receiving `Expression<Func<TController, Func<T1, T2>>>` from `ForController`. In other words, when `ForControllerImplementation` is invoked `TDelegate` is actually `Func<T1, T2>`. I'm passing the signature of the method in as type parameters to `ForController` so that I can use a lambda like `c => c.getEventsById` without having to call it.

Comment: As an experiment, in `ForController()` try doing something like `((MethodCallExpression) expression.Body).Method`. See if that doesn't work. If it does, you may consider refactoring to follow that route.

Comment: Got the same error - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression'.

Comment: Yup, gonna have to rebuild it sounds like. It's really not too hard to do though.

Comment: Updated again. Maybe this actually might help.

Comment: reading back through this... excellent answer. Thank you again for taking the time to go through this with me!!

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is a lot simpler than all of this. The problem is your lambda expression signature is as such:

```
Expression<Func<TController, Func<T1, T2>>> expression
```

So you delegate signature is :

```
Func<TController, Func<T1, T2>>
or
Func<T1, T2> function(TController controller){}
```

That function takes a TController as input as returns a delegate (`Func<T1, T2>`); Whereas your implementation lambda that you are passing `(c => c.GetEventsById)` has a signature of:

```
Expression<Func<TController, T1>> expression
```

So your compiled lambda delegate signature is:

```
Func<EventsController, int> 
or
int function(EventsController controller){}
```

So you are getting a UnaryExpression in the body because it represents the delegate conversion (which I'm assuming would throw an exception if you tried to compile/invoke it `-> Expression.Compile().Invoke()`). Make your signatures match and your Expression Body will be a methodCallExpression.